# How to bend a segment of a mesh?

Tags: modeling

I recently started using Blender for a special request. I wanted to model a logo, which is a pencil.

When I started modelling the pencil, I got stuck at a certain point, I wanted to bend the segments at the tip of the pen, between the paint and the wood, to look a bit more realistic. I searched for the answer everywhere on the web but found nothing.

[image: screenshot showing the problem on my blender workspace]

Answer (score 3):

you can try this:

subdivide, then checker deselect, and with proportional editing move it as you like:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Might autosmooth afterwards to avoid ngon shading problems :)

Comment: Yes. You are right, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> How to bend a segment of a mesh?

...I wouldn't bend anything there.

I would solve this with a shader if I were you, because the way you want to bend the vertices, you would always get a weird mesh somehow due to the face triangulation.

But if you keep the structure of the mesh very simple and use only planar faces, you can draw the curved line with a shader.

To do this, you would need to enable *Auto Smooth* so that the edge is drawn smoothly at the transition between paint and wood.

Then create a *UVMap* in which this edge runs in the middle.

The shader will then create a waveform based on this centerline (adjust it to your exact specifications).

This will give you pretty much the result you've sketched here.

[image]

[image]